# Any Tensorflow-text >= 2.11.0 Windows installer available?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

From 2.11.0 version there is no `Tensorflow-text` Windows installer as stated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#a-note-about-different-operating-system-packages)
Is it any available 3rd-party build for Windows available?
I googled it but even didn't find any mention.